# Attaching an entity with a child entity in the DB context

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a **UserEntity** that has a child **PlayerEntity**. I perform the following sequence of actions:

1. In the first DB context I get the **UserEntity** including **PlayerEntity**.
2. I save the **UserEntity** in memory.
3. In the second DB context, I first get the **PlayerEntity** from the DB and then want to use the **UserEntity** from memory. To do this I am attaching a **UserEntity** to the context.
4. I get an error with the text:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The instance of entity type 'PlayerEntity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values."

```cs
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            UserEntity userEntity = null!;

            using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
            {
                userEntity = await db
                    .Users
                    .Include(u => u.Players)
                    .Where(u => u.Id.ToString() == "c459e72f-87c4-421a-fbfa-08db11fa37cc")
                    .FirstAsync();
            }

            using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
            {
                PlayerEntity playerEntity = await db
                    .Players
                    .Where(u => u.Id == userEntity.Players.First().Id)
                    .FirstAsync();

                EntityState state = db.Entry(userEntity).State;

                if (state == EntityState.Detached)
                {
                    db.Attach(userEntity);
                }

                userEntity.FirstName = "New Name";

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Why am I doing this in this order?
I want to use IMemoryCache to cache data in application memory. Sometimes it happens that according to business logic, I first need to get a child entity and only then the parent. In this order, I will receive the above error.

What is usually done in such cases? Maybe there is a best practice for this?

I think I can make a second UserEntityLite on the same table but without the child entities. And use only UserEntityLite for cache storage. But I think this is not the best solution.

Comment: You can avoid this error with `db.Detach(playerEntity)`. As you attach the `userEntity` it will also attach the dependent entities `Players`.

Comment: I have the playerEntity reference only in the example. In a business application I use UserService and PlayerService with cache.
1. If the user entity is in the cache, then the service automatically attaches it to the database context and returns a link.
2. If the user entity is not in the cache, then the service retrieves it from the database, places it in the cache and returns a link.Thus, the entity is always in context. But UserService doesn't know about PlayerService.
If I first get the entity from PlayerService and then want to get the entity from UserService then I will get an error.

Comment: I'd always offer a clone of a cached entity object to protect the cache. But should cached object tracked anyway? Why not get them with `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: I use tracking to ensure that only changed properties are updated at the database level. If you use Update(Entity) then all columns will be updated and on child entities too. And I think that after updating the child entity, it will become tracked, so the same error will occur.